# How to apply shape keys in Blender 3.4?

Tags: shape-keys

How to appy shape keys in Blender? I've read all kind of posts here but none is working at all! Please if anyone knows a working solution to applay shape keys tell me. Thank you

Comment: I don't think it has changed recently, click on the drop down right of the shape keys list, Apply all shape keys ?

Comment: That's weird, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The shape key list does not have that button anymore.

For 3.4 I found that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> *Apply > Visual Geometry to Mesh* does the trick. Actually it's the only working way I found.

Comment: It works, but the issue is that it will apply many things other than shape keys if you have them.

Answer (score 0):

It's right here in the *Shape Key Specials* drop-down menu:

[image: apply shapekeys]